# how to use the system call dup?

Tags: c, shell

I am trying to understand how the system call dup() works. I am asking this question because I am writing a shell in C and I need to redirect the STDOUT to a file. Is this the right way to do it?

If for example I have the following code:

```
remember = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
fileDescriptor = open("file.txt",O_RDONLY);
```

then everything that writes to the stdout will now write to the opened file?

As soon as the following line is executed:

```
remember = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
```

STDOUT_FILENO is removed from the table of file descriptors leaving the first spot empty. When a new file is opened, the earliest empty file descriptor will be appointed to this new opened file, so in this case 1.

Comment: Of course not. The `dup` makes a copy of the `stdout` fd. But what makes you think anything in that code would connect `stdout` or the `remember` fd to to the open file? The file was not even open yet at the time that `dup` was called. Please do a search. There are lots of examples of how this is done.

Comment: I am going to update the thread, so I explain my thinking.

Comment: `dup` does not close the original file descriptor. Perhaps you are thinking of `dup2` which does.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You just duplicate the file descriptor for stdout.

With the code you have so far, you could now do a write to remember, and the output would go to console, too:

```
char str = "this now goes to console, too!";
write(remember, str, strlen(str));
```

If you want to redirect console output, you yet have to do this:

```
dup2(fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

This will close `STDOUT_FILENO` (but you have a duplicate in `remember` to restore it, if need be) and overwrite it with `fileDescriptor` – and from now on, console output goes to file...

If you don't ever consider to restore outputting to console, you can ommit the first call to `dup` entirely...

Edit (in response to your edit):

> STDOUT_FILENO is removed from the table of file descriptors leaving the first spot empty. When a new file is opened, the earliest empty file descriptor will be appointed to this new opened file, so in this case 1.

This applies for `close(STDOUT_FILENO)`!

So back to if not wanting to restore: You could then do, too:

```
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
fileDescriptor = open("file.txt",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
// fileDescriptor will be 1 now
```

By the way: You must open your file with write access enabled (O_WRONLY or O_RDWR), as you want to write to that file (redirect output to)!

And you need the O_CREAT flag for the case the file does not exist yet. If you do not want to clear the file, but append to, add the O_APPEND flag (see [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html)).

Comment: in dup2(fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO), are you sure that the order of the arguments is right?

Comment: `man dup2`, the prototype is `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);` mystery solved.

Answer (score 0):

No `dup` is used to **duplicate** an existing descriptor and returning a duplicate whose value is the less possible among free descriptors (some docs says *``The new descriptor returned by the call is the lowest
     numbered descriptor currently not in use by the process.''*), so:

```
fileDescriptor = open("file.txt",O_RDONLY); // get new desc.
close(STDIN_FILENO);                        // close 0
dup(fileDescriptor);                        // dup new desc to 0 (less possible free desc).
// here fileDescriptor and 0 are aliases to the same opened file
close(fileDescriptor);                      // free unused desc.
```